# Python Error: Threaded Matplotlib (Pyplot) Plotting - x and y do not have same first dimension

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pickle

This is part of a multi-threaded python script (threading.thread) with data transfer via queues that has an error when trying to plot the data gathered using pyplot in matplotlib.

This entire script worked in a previous version; the only change is I store and load the data arrays using pickle.dump and pickle.load respectively. In this debugging version, there is no loading enabled.

Here is the relevant code that fails, broken up by the containing thread:

IN THE MAIN LOOP (THREAD):

```
elif kbcheck == 'p':
                    print "I KNOW YOU TYPED P" # Debug to see if plotting is triggered.
                    PLOTFLAGQ.put(1)
```

IN THE DATA PROCESSING THREAD:

```
self.PLOTQL = [self.RAL, self.THD_avgL, self.VacL,
                       self.IacL, self.PacL, self.VdcL,
                       self.IdcL, self.PdcL, self.tempL]
if not self.PLOTFLAGQ.empty():
                self.plotflag = self.PLOTFLAGQ.get()
                self.PLOTQ.put(self.PLOTQL)
```

IN THE PLOTTING THREAD:

```
if not self.PLOTQ.empty():
                (self.RAL, self.THD_avgL, self.VacL, self.IacL,
                 self.PacL, self.VdcL, self.IdcL, self.PdcL,
                 self.TempL) = self.PLOTQ.get()
self.XaxisL = []
                for i in range(len(self.VacL)):
                    self.XaxisL.append(i+1)
self.fig = pyplot.figure()
self.gs = gridspec.GridSpec(6,1, height_ratios = [1,2,2,2,2,2])
self.sT = pyplot.subplot(self.gs[0])
self.sT.yaxis.set_major_locator(pyplot.MaxNLocator(5))
self.sV = pyplot.subplot(self.gs[1])
self.sV.yaxis.set_major_locator(pyplot.MaxNLocator(10))
self.Va = self.sV.plot(self.XaxisL,self.VacL,
                                       '-b',label = 'Voltage (AC)')
```

Here is the debug information:

```
17
Here is the info in the Plot Thread
the length of VacL is: 17
[250.119, 250.156, 250.19, 250.193, 250.206, 250.158, 250.107, 250.103, 250.159, 250.156, 250.146, 250.093, 250.084, 250.095, 250.134, 250.0
35, 249.994]

the length of the x axis is: 17
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Above the output shows the count of the sampling (17), then the Vac list array and its length, followed by the x axis array (derived from the length of the other values).

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Projects\PythonScripts\Matthew_Threading_2_v0.3.3db.py", line 273, in run
    self.Va = self.sV.plot(self.XaxisL,self.VacL,"-b",label = "Voltage AC")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 3848, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 323, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 300, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 240, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

I have rewritten the entire program twice, and rewritten just the saving thread (the part that seems to break the plotting) two more times and can't figure out what is causing this error.

If anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: why don't you do `self.XaxisL = np.arange(len(self.VacL)) + 1` ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this bug _not_ in your threaded program?  That is in code that we could actually run/test?

Comment: Why are you doing all of this in attributes?  Could you make most of the variables in the plotting thread function local variables instead of attributes?  I strongly suspect you actually have a race condition that we can not help you with from the information provided.

Comment: I did use the arange technique in one of the iterations, but changed it back to one that I know worked in previous versions.

Comment: I will try to reproduce the error in a smaller program this weekend.

Both of the print statements in the answer below immediately before the plot command (the results are in the debug section above)

I will try to debug in the try except blocks but I might not have access to the GPIB/visa equipment until Tuesday.

Comment: I want to see the value of the arrays just _after_ the call.  If this is a race condition, you have no guarantee that the values printed are the values the function was called with.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your plotting command with this code:

```
try:
    self.Va = self.sV.plot(self.XaxisL,self.VacL,'-b',label = 'Voltage (AC)')
except ValueError:
    print len(self.XaxisL), len(self.VacL)
    print self.XaxisL, self.VacL
```

and see what you get.  I suspect you have a race condition.